# Ступенчатый массив c#

Tags: c#

Не получается заполнить ступенчатый массив, арифметической прогрессией из другого однородного массива. (длина строки ступенчатого, то есть кол-во слагаемых прогрессии - соответствующий элемент второго однородного массива)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ruSO!
Прикладывание картинок с кодом является моветоном, так как затрудняется воспроизведение Вашего кода.

Пожалуйста, приложите Ваш код текстом согласно требований форматирования.

Comment: Другими словами, мне лень перепечатывать код с картинки, чтобы дать ответ, вставье пожалуйста его текстом. Судя по коду, это Winforms, так же добавьте тег `winforms` к вопросу.

Comment: Мне тоже лень перепечатывать код с картинки, поэтому отвечать на вопрос не буду. Минус на вопросе мой, готов снять если автор вставит код текстом.

Comment: рекомендую вам почитать: [оформление кода](https://habr.com/ru/post/26077/), [интерполяция строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation), [массивы](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.4.php), [`int.ToString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 2):

У вас вложенный массив. Вы инициализировали его, но не инициализировали его подммассивы.

Во втором по счёту цикле `for(i = 0; i < elems; i++)` инициализируйте подмассивы строчкой `myArr[i] = new int[ a2[i]-1 ]`. Должно получиться так:

```
for(i = 0; i < elems; i++)
{
    myArr[i] = new int[ a2[i]-1 ];

    for(j = 0; j < a2[i]-1; j++)
        myArr[i][j] = a1[i] + j;
}
```

Comment: Я уже сделал это, но всё равно
for (i = 0; i < elems; i++)
            {
                myArr[i] = new int[a2[i]-1];
            
            for (j=0 ; j < myArr[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    myArr[i][j] = a1[i] + j;
                }
          
            }

Comment: @Timurik добавьте новый код и скриншот новой ошибки в вопрос

Comment: @aepot исправил